# Persistent data at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, data-persistence

Is there a way to persist data in a view during Runtime only,  as user navigates between views.

ie user answers a question in a view sets a bool flag so if user navigates  back to question view the question is already answered . 
When user quits app the bool flag should not persist.

Hope that makes sense.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a perfect solution but your application is singleton and storing data there is one option. However, I would seriously consider redesigning your app.

Comment: Actually yes as soon as I posted I thought a redesign Is prob best option